# argparse to validated unknown args in python

Tags: python, argparse

test1.py:

```
_argParserObj = argparse.ArgumentParser()
_argParserObj.add_argument('--tool', type=str, dest='tool')
parsedArgs, passthroughs = _argParserObj.parse_known_args()
```

When test1.py is executed as below

```
test1.py --tool abc arg1 arg2 --invalid_switch
```

I would like to show the below error.
But still accept arg1 and arg2 as extra arguments

> test1.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -invalid_switch

Currently it just parses `invalid_switch` also a passthrough and throw any error.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: But still accept arg1 and arg2 as extra arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can try `parse_args()` instead of `parse_known_args()`

```
_argParserObj = argparse.ArgumentParser()
_argParserObj.add_argument('--tool', type=str, dest='tool')
parsedArgs, passthroughs = _argParserObj.parse_args()
```

`parse_args()` will show this error in your case

```
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --invalid_switch
```

Comment: parse_args() will through error for arg1 and arg2 as well. I need to  consider arg1 and arg2 as unknownargs(passthroughs similar to perl), but throw error for invalid switch

Comment: You could do `_argParserObj.add_argument("args", nargs="*")` to have `parse_known_args()` "know" about arguments as well as flags.